# Añadir variables en consulta mysqli_query mediante php

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php



//conexión//
$servername = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

//post variables//
$account_server = $_POST["account_server"];
$account_server = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $account_server);
$account_type = $_POST["account_type"];
$account_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $account_type);
$unranked_type = $_POST["unranked_type"];
$unranked_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $unranked_type);
$ranked_type = $_POST["ranked_type"];
$ranked_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ranked_type);
$account_username = $_POST["account_username"];
$account_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $account_username);
$account_password = $_POST["account_password"];
$account_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $account_password);

//consultas//
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Cuentas (Server,Account_Class,Unranked_Type,Ranked_Type,Username,Password) VALUES('$account_server','$account_type','$unranked_type','$ranked_type','$account_username','$account_password')");


$notificationmsg1;

if ($query1) {
    $notificationmsg1 = "La cuenta ha sido agregada a la base de datos correctamente.";
    echo $notificationmsg1;
} else if (!$query1) {
    $notificationmsg1 = "No se pudo agregar la cuenta a la base de datos correctamente.";
    echo $notificationmsg1;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Siempre al procesarse el php me salta el mensaje de "No se pudo agregar la cuenta a la base de datos correctamente."

He comprobado ya:

1) Las strings y sus respectivas informaciones son importadas correctamente desde mi `form` HTML mediante `$_POST`.

2) La conexión con la base de datos se establece correctamente.

¿Probablemente tenga algún fallo de sintaxis? ¿O el error se debe a otra cosa?
 Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda. :)

Comment: No estás usando correctamente MySQLi. Debes **1º preparar tu consulta** y **2º ejecutarla**. En el código no haces ni una ni otra cosa. Mira los ejemplos #1 o #2 del Manual, adapta el código y verás que funciona: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php Es importante **que comprendas la utilidad de usar consultas preparadas**, pues existen para prevenir contra la **Inyección SQL**. En teoría, se deben enviar por separado la cadena SQL en sí y los datos. La forma en que lo haces ahora, aunque funcionara, sería insegura. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas también esto: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php y http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php pues lo de la **Inyección SQL** no es algo banal.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que algo no sea correcto en tu consulta SQL.

Te puedes apoyar en `mysqli_error()` para mostrar los errores que se produzcan en la consulta.

Añade:

```
echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

Después de ejecutar tu consulta o en `elseif` que tienes.

Comment: Lo más incorrecto de todo este código es **no usar consultas preparadas**. Es un código **totalmente vulnerable para recibir inyección SQL** que podría borrar todas las tablas y hasta tomar el control de la base de datos en cuanto la consulta, como la tiene planteada, funcione.

Comment: Por favor ¿has visto el código del compañero?  Esta escapando los datos de forma adecuada [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) lo único que se le puede criticar en ese aspecto es no establecer el juego de caracteres.  Las sentencias preparadas no siempre son la mejor opción, véase la documentación.

Comment: ¿Crees que escapar las cadenas es un método seguro contra la inyección SQL?   Te equivocas. Mira esto: https://www.adampalmer.me/iodigitalsec/2013/08/18/mysql_real_escape_string-wont-magically-solve-your-sql-injection-problems/  Además, la documentación dice claramente que siempre que tomes datos desde fuera **debes usar sentencias preparadas**: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php Te recomiendo que leas esto también:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/cómo-evitar-la-inyección-sql-en-php Saludos.

Comment: He revisado tus enlaces y en todos se proporciona mysqli_real_escape_string como alternativa siempre que sea usado de forma adecuada. mysqli_real_escape_string es seguro para escapar cadenas de texto solo hay que utilizarla de forma correcta. Un buen hilo para que entiendas lo que digo puede ser [este](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string).  Esto no quita que se recomienden sentencias preparadas.

Comment: lee el enlace que te puse en el anterior comentario al respecto y los comentarios al enlace que me has enviado. Verás que varios usuarios dicen lo mismo : escapar cadenas no siempre te permite escapar de una inyección. **Consultas preparadas** es  el camino.

Comment: No pretendo continuar con esta discusión, no tiene sentido. Ambos métodos son igual de válidos, de hecho utilizar sentencias preparadas malamente o en ciertas versiones puede ser tan vulnerable como cualquier otro método. Leí tus enlaces, y mysqli_real_escape_string no es vulnerable si se utiliza adecuadamente. De hecho los ejemplos de ataques demostrados son por un mal uso de la función,  utilizada para escapar números no cadenas o por no establecer el juego de caracteres de forma explícita y adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

El error que veo en tu código, es que, no has añadido la `Base de datos` con la que va a trabajar tu `conexión`.

Tu código:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, BD.....);
                                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Código actualizado:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "Base_de_datos");
```

Posiblemente con eso te funcionara el código.

Tambien podrias mandar un *error* en caso que fallara tu sentencia `insert`.

```
if (!$query1) {
    //Error.
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    //Notificación.
    $notificationmsg1 = "No se pudo agregar la cuenta a la base de datos correctamente.";
    echo $notificationmsg1;
} else {
    $notificationmsg1 = "La cuenta ha sido agregada a la base de datos correctamente..";
    echo $notificationmsg1;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

> **Nota:** ahora bien, si quieres obtener mayor seguridad, te dejo una segunda respuesta.

Para mayor seguridad ante ataques de `SQL`, es mejor utilizar sentencia `preparadas` o `PDO` como ya te han mencionado. Podrás encontrar información aquí ante [como evitar la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

**Un posible ejemplo Mysqli prepare():**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {

    //Obtenemos datos
    $account_server = $_POST["account_server"] ?: '';
    $account_type = $_POST["account_type"] ?: '';
    $unranked_type = $_POST["unranked_type"] ?: '';
    $ranked_type = $_POST["ranked_type"] ?: '';
    $account_username = $_POST["account_username"] ?: '';
    $account_password = $_POST["account_password"] ?: '';

    //Verdadero datos.
    if ($account_server && $account_type && $unranked_type && $ranked_type && $account_username && $account_password) {

        //Importante llamar a conexion donde se va utilizar.
        $conn = new mysqli("servidor", "usuaio", "contraseña", "basedatos");

        /* verificar conexión */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("La conexión fallo: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        //Sentencia preparada.
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Cuentas (Server,Account_Class,Unranked_Type,Ranked_Type,Username,Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        /*  ¡IMPORTANTE, Especificación del tipo de caracteres de tus variables!

            i   la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
            d   la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
            s   la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
            b   la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes
        */      
        $rc = $query->bind_param("sissss",$account_server,$account_type,$unranked_type,$ranked_type,$account_username,$account_password);

        if ( false===$rc ) {            
            die('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($query->error));
        }

        $rc = $query->execute(); //Ejecutar sentencia.

        if ( false===$rc ) {
            die('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($query->error));
        } else {            
            echo "La cuenta ha sido agregada a la base de datos correctamente.";
        }

        $query->close();//Cerramos sentencia.    

    }

}

?>
```

Manual [mysqli::prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: ¿Sólo ves ese error? Y... ¿qué hay de la inyección SQL? Es hasta mejor que ese código no funcione pues si funciona y alguien escribe en el último $_POST lo siguiente: 1; DELETE FROM unatabla; DELETE FROM otratabla; ettttttc ya sabes lo que pasaría. Me parece grave que se aporten respuestas sin advertir sobre un error mucho más grave como es no usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ese dato de la inyección ya lo habías aclarado tú mismo en un comentario anteriormente, para que volver a advertirle. Simplemente contesto a su fallo, que es en lo que se base la pregunta.

Comment: No estaría de más indicárselo al menos en una nota, en la respuesta. A veces los comentarios son ignorados porque se busca una solución fácil a los problemas, el camino corto que a veces conduce a situaciones lamentables. En realidad una solución basada en código obsoleto e inseguro es solo una solución ilusoria. Quizá luego tendremos al OP de regreso diciendo que ha perdido todos sus datos y que no entiende por qué. Creo que responder para hacer que en un código vulnerable funcione, en vez de resolver el problema crea otro mayor. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, tienes razón, a veces vamos directo a lo fácil, y no leemos pequeñas cosas importantes, ahora edito mi respuesta con un ejemplo preparada. Un saludo.